# Update class information in jquery after action and serialize button's id for ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two buttons, like these:

```
<td>
<button id="1" class="green-button">Upublicznij</button>
<button id="1" class="yellow-button">Usuń</button>
</td>
```

Button `green-button` and `red-button` have different actions in Jquery.

I take them clicked from `$('button.yellow-button').on('click', function(form)`

And somewhere in code I change them for example, if we click `yellow-button` then:

```
this_button.attr('class', 'green-button');
this_button.html('Upublicznij');
```

`yellow-button` becomes `green-button`.

But next, when I click this button still action called is

`$('button.yellow-button').on('click', function(form)`

But... this is `green-button` now, so It should call action `$('button.green-button').on('click', function(form)` as for green-buttons actions. To work properly I have to refresh page

How to update it? I think jquery doesn't know button class has changed and for jquery it's still yellow...

And one another thing, as you can see I have two id's the same in both buttons, one is for publicate and another for unpublicate. in jquery ajax I take this id from: `data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },` to make POSTs request. How Can I seperate these two thins to have like:

```
<button id="publicate-1"...
<button id="unpublicate-1"...
```

But still take only this "number" of ID that I need to process in ajax PHP POST request? How to take only these numbers to json as ID? Can I do something like serialize this button that will take only these numbers?

Like in `sortable('serialize')` that cuts `<li id='item=5'>....` to only number 5 without `item` word

Comment: Why don't you keep a common `class` which doesn't change so that you don't need to depend on 2 events?

Comment: Because green class has green style in css etc... yellow different too

Comment: Yea fine, you can add remove them, but why not single class here just for attaching event? as in `<button id="1" class="green-button btn">` where in you attach events to `btn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the proper solution given below.

```
$(document).on('click','button', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var obj = $(this);
   var checkPoint = obj.attr('class');
   switch(checkPoint){
      case 'green-button':
           // Code for green-button action
           obj.removeClass('green-button').addClass('yellow-button');
           break;
      case 'yellow-button':
           // Code for yellow-button action
           obj.removeClass('yellow-button').addClass('green-button');
           break;
      default:
           // Default Action
           break;
   }
});
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: @KrystianPolska : Glad to help you out from this hurdle.